# The best way to store restart information in spring-batch readers, processors, writers and tasklets

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Currently I'm designing my first batch application with spring batch using several tasklets and own readers, writers and processors primarily doing  input data checks and tif-file handling (split, merge etc) depending on the input data i.e. document metadata with the appertaining image files. I want to store and use restart information persistet in the batch_step_execution_context in the spring-batch job-repository. Unfortunately I did not find many examples where and how to do this best. I want to make the application restartable so that it can continue after error correction at the point it left off.

What I have done so far and checked if in case of an exception the step information has been persistet:

- Implemented ItemStream in a CustomItemWriter using update() and open() to store and regain information to/from the step_execution_context e.g. executionContext.putLong("count", count). Works good.
- Used StepListeners and found that the context information written in beforeStep() has been persistet. Also works.

I appreciate help which will give or point to some examples, "restart tutorial" or sources where to read how to do it in Readers, Processors, Writers and tasklets. Does it make sense in Readers and Processors? I'm aware that handling restart information might also depend on commit-interval,  restartable flags etc..

Remark: Maybe I require some deeper understanding of spring-batch concepts beyond what I read and tried so far. Also hints regarding this are welcome. I consider myself as intermediate level lacking details to make my application using some comforts of spring-batch.

Comment: Please do not confuse [tag:spring]-batch and [tag:batch-file]...

Comment: Why are you basically reinventing what spring batch already does for you (unless you are implementing your own readers and writers which is imho rarely needed). If you are implementing your own take a look at the sources of the spring proved readers/writers on how they use and persists state.